# Question about libc_write()

Tags: c++, libc

I'm trying to determine what libc_write does exactly.  I'm executing a binary on a processor simulator I designed in c++ and the program being run has jumped to the function call libc_write().  Now, there are 2 different types of write functions - write() which writes one large buffer to a stream, possibly comprised of many buffers that were copied contiguously in memory from other buffers - and writev() which takes an array of pointers to one or many buffers along with each buffer's size and writes them all to a single stream.  What does libc_write do?  Write, Writev, both, none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libc_write` is the LIBC's internal [alias](http://www.ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html#func-alias) for `write(3)`. Since `writev(3)` boils down to a separate [syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/writev), you'd see `libc_writev` if you were calling it.

A side note - make [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) your friend :)

#### Edit:

`(3)` means section 3 of [the manual](http://linuxmanpages.com):

> `1. General Commands
> 2. System Calls
> 3. Subroutines
> 4. Special Files
> 5. File Formats
> 6. Games
> 7. Macros and Conventions
> 8. Maintenence Commands`

I.e. `write(2)` means manual entry for `write` *system call*. `write(3)` means manual entry for `write` *library routine*.

Comment: You may need to explain what (3) means to this OP